# Wordpress OOP get current user question?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a simple plugin that Iam trying to use to learn OOP, please bear with me. I am setting up a part of it to show front end account data and want to grab the current user info. I know how to do this procedurally but I'm confused how to do this in OOP, I keep getting undefined function errors.

The structure for the class is set up as follows:

```
<?php 

class FendAccount {

    public $user;

    public function __construct () {

    }

    public function set_user(){

    }


} //END OF CLASS

$frontend = new FendAccount;
echo $frontend;

?>
```

This is in a separate class file that is being required by the main plugin PHP file and so should be firing as the plugin is loaded.

Am I rigght in thinking that a method that sets the property $user will be the best way to do this, so that I can call that method/object wherever I want in the plugin whenever I need to work with the current user? or is that overkill because wordpress already provides this functionality.

Or, should I just add a function to my main plugin PHP file that populates a global $current_user with the current user details via wp_get_current_user?

Thanks

Comment: I would avoid global variables at all costs, they're not OO. Also, `$frontend` contains an object in your example, so it doesn't make sense to `echo $frontend;`. You mention you're getting undefined function errors, can you share them along with the code you're trying to use? Are you trying to access this PHP file directly? ( if so that would explain the undefined function errors )

Comment: Apologies the echo at the end had been echo $frontend -> user;

Comment: I've deleted all my code out of frustration as I couldn't figure it out. The procedural version is so much simpler in the short run, but longer in the long run - it's a mind mess making the transition to oop!

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect the actual code? Are you loading this in a plugin or are you visiting that file directly in the browser? Or is this in a theme? Where is the class located and how are you loading the file? It isn't clear how you're running your code, or where it's being ran from, which is important to know, especially for `wp_get_current_user` which can't just be called at any time